# How to use react-i18next to change language by different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I code an open source project [Poker Coder](https://github.com/ningowood/poker-coder) recently.

After English to Chinese translation for each card's intro, I cannot find a good way to toggle language by using react-i18next.

In the official document of [React i18next](https://react.i18next.com/), every example is just a simple json file written in `public/locales/xx/translation.json`, but I want to load language config by different JavaScript files in `src` like this file structure:

```
# src/poker
.
├── index.ts
└── poker-coder
    ├── cn
    │   ├── club.ts
    │   ├── diamond.ts
    │   ├── heart.ts
    │   ├── joker.ts
    │   └── spade.ts
    └── en
        ├── club.ts
        ├── diamond.ts
        ├── heart.ts
        ├── joker.ts
        └── spade.ts
```

What can I do? I would be appreciate if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the official document of React i18next, every example is just a simple json file written in public/locales/xx/translation.json, but I want to load language config by different JavaScript files

Lets clarify - you want to use some package but not in the way it works? It's simple - just fork it and change to your needs!

Don't you think that something is wrong with your process?
**You should check i18next requirements first then prepare translations.**

... but lucky you ... i18next is very flexible

1. for small project you can import (hardcode, compile in) all your translations - [docs](https://react.i18next.com/legacy-v9/step-by-step-guide) method from point 1b - **just import all files from anywhere** (src paths) - recompile the whole app on translation changes
2. for separate **loading at run time you have to provide .json file translations in publicly available path**

For file conversion needed in second method you can use babel ( [babel-plugin-i18next-extract](https://i18next-extract.netlify.com/) ) but configuring it can be harder.

Comment: That's helpful, and as u say, configuring babel is harder for me. Finally, my solution is think of all Poker info as a async data but not a ```translation config file```, thus i can use Redux to load async Poker info data after ```i18n.changeLanguage(value)``` api changed the global language! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call i18n.changeLanguage(value); //value can be 'es' or 'en' depend upon the language you want to be on the website. then this changeLanguage() method will call to i18n config file which will further call to your translated  file in which the translation text you have putted.

Comment: Thx, ```i18n.changeLanguage()``` worked well, and I know the i18n config had changed the language by this api. 

It seems my real question is where and which api to put my translated file into i18n config, and i18n can automatic important different translation file after ```changeLanguage()``` worked.

Comment: Problem resolved! My solution is think of all Poker info as a async data but not a ```translation config file```, thus i can use Redux to load async Poker info data after ```i18n.changeLanguage(value)``` api changed the global language! :)